# Recording remote test executions from Selenium Grid

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, video-recording

I have automated scripts (Java + Selenium + Cucumber), which I run remotely using Selenium Grid. I would like to record execution in a way that each test case has separate video with appropriate name, preferably test name or at least session id.

Is there any way to achieve that? Monte Screen Recorder, which I'm using on local machine, unfortunately doesn't work with Grid.